# Protected Access for Instance Members in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, protected

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I access C# protected members except like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567705/why-cant-i-access-c-sharp-protected-members-except-like-this)

*As I was reading a c# book (special annotated version which shows all the tricky part of c#)*

I saw this code :

```
public class A
{
    protected int x;
    static void F(A a, B b)
    {
        a.x = 1; // Okay
        b.x = 1; // Okay
    }
}
public class B: A
{
    static void F(A a, B b)
    {
        a.x = 1; // Error: must access through instance of B
        b.x = 1; // Okay
    }
}
```

looking at `protected` meanning :

> Access limited to this class or classes derived from this class

**Questions**

- Why does this restriction (via *instances*) exists ?
- Can you **please** supply an example of a problematic situation as if it was allowed ?

Comment: This is a msdn example and had removed the important part: within A, it is possible to access x through instances of both A and B, since in either case the access takes place through an instance of A or a class derived from A. However, within B, it is not possible to access x through an instance of A, since A does not derive from B. You could even manipulate x if you derived C from B via c.x = , but not via a. you have access to the current class instance variables, not the parent class ones instance whise speaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoted meaning of protected is not the technical definition, but merely what the spec quotes as the intuitive meaning (section 3.5.1):

> The intuitive meaning of protected is “access limited to the
>   containing class or types derived from the containing class”.

Further down in the same section it gives a more rigorous definition (Here M is member of a type T):

> Otherwise, if M is protected, the access is permitted if it occurs
>   within the class in which M is declared, or if it occurs within a
>   class derived from the class in which M is declared and takes place
>   through the derived class type (§3.5.3).

The referenced section (3.5.3) is specifically about protected member access and contains your example with the note:

> This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing protected
>   members of other derived classes, even when the members are inherited
>   from the same base class.

Thus the answer is clear. It is designed to prevent a third class from doing something like this:

```
public class C : A
{
  public static void F(A a, B b, C c)
  {
     a.x = 1; // not allowed
     b.x = 1; // not allowed
     c.x = 1; // allowed
  }
}
```

With your definition of `protected` the first two assignments would be allowed. This would be rather odd. Say I had my library and I defined `A` and `B` but I let you inherit from `A`  and you wrote `C`. I would be a little alarmed as a library author that some one could modify the internal details in instances of classes that I wrote! Sure you could expose modification of the field `x` in `C` through a property or method but that behavior is limited to instances of your class `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good answer to your second question

> This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing protected members of other
>       derived classes, even when the members are inherited from the same base class.

Here's the link to the existing question

[Is there a way to reach a `protected` member of another object from a derived type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344503/is-there-a-way-to-reach-a-protected-member-of-another-object-from-a-derived-ty)